# AWS CodeBuild nodejs image with aws cli v2 installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, docker-image

We are building our project and we have to use AWS CLI v2 to deploy our project.

The runtime version that we use is this one:

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12.x
```

Is there an official AWS CodeBuild nodejs image that we can use that has AWS CLI v2 installed or do we need to create our own. Is there an elegant way to upgrade to v2 for the above runtime?

This seems that it works but it might not be very stable in the future:

```
 # uninstall awscli version 1
 - pip3 uninstall -y awscli
 # install awscli version 2
 - curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
 - unzip awscliv2.zip
 - ./aws/install
```

Comment: Official images use cli v1. The snipped you showed, does not work?

Comment: @Marcin it does work, but it might be a bit fragile in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments, I can add a little bit of more info.

Official CB docker images are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html). The **two newest ones** are

- [aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/tree/master/al2/x86_64/standard/3.0) for Amazon Linux 2
- [aws/codebuild/standard:4.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/tree/master/ubuntu/standard/4.0) for Ubuntu 18.04

Both these images are also open sourced (links above). Thus, we can **inspect** their `Dockerfile` files.

In both of them, `awscli` is installed in a similar way:

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade setuptools wheel aws-sam-cli awscli boto3 pipenv virtualenv
```

As we can see, this  installs `awscliv1`.

Instructions for installing `awscliv2` are [different](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-install) and they do not involve `pip`.